# music sampler control

Tags: control-systems

I'm a reasonably competent web programmer and I would like to know how I should go about learning to program a software that would control a music sampler.

The hardware setup I was given is a sampler
( Example : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akai_S3000XL or http://www.vintagesynth.com/yamaha/a3000 )
and a PC, but this can be extended.

Somebody should be able to operate the sampler from anywhere by means of a web page that shows a sort of a control panel which should be identical in function and form with the one of the sampler. Then they should save / download the result.
I'm not sure this is the right place to ask, but I don't have any other ideas.

Software wise I can do anything on the webstack (PHP, Javascript, Python, .Net), and also Java, and C++ if need be. I have no experience with Rust, and I won't touch Assembly.

Hardware wise, what kind of hardware setup should I be looking for? This is what I don't understand actually: how to interface with the samplers.

If there's anything like an idiot's guide to control some random machine from a PC, please point me to it.
Thanks for any help, it is much appreciated.

Comment: Old samplers likely have to be programmed via MIDI sysex messages. That is a low bandwidth link and proprietary protocol usage. Newer samplers might use USB as a carrier for MIDI-like messages, or USB more directly. There are a number of editor/librarian apps for synths, perhaps you can find some to study. I would think that for a sampler, you want to dump more data in order to inspect the waveform. What is your motivation for doing this, rather than going for a PC based sampler?

Comment: My son is very interested in music, although not especially hard working. Long story short, one of his teachers thought it would be interesting / helpful to have some means to allow the students to use the samplers from home. Corona affects us all. Anyway all the processing or whatever would still be done on the sampler, it would just be controlled from home. I've been volunteered to study the problem because I'm the only parent in his class who does anything 'serious' computer related.